# Accessing mesos slave informations through an internet box

Tags: mesos

I am setting a marathon/mesos dockerized network by distance.

the network setting is :

```
Laptop <-> internet <-> box (known IP) <-> Serveur (192.168.x.x : mesos/marathon)
```

From my laptop I can see mesos's interface :

```
Firefox : http://@box-IP:mesos-port
```

I can see slaves and tasks running : so things are pretty ok. But when clicking on a slave's Sandbox, I have the following errors :

```
Failed to connect to slave 'c1070c02-3754-4ae2-8ca0-1d0d2ec879e7-S22' on 'HP-xw8600-Workstation:5053'.
Potential reasons:
1) The slave's hostname, 'HP-xw8600-Workstation', is not accessible from your network
2) The slave's port, '5053', is not accessible from your network
3) The slave timed out or went offline
```

But if I do a [ssh -X] followed by a [firefox hhtp://192.168.X.X:mesos-port] and click on the slave's sandbox link, the message disappear, and I do see the slave's page.

So I conclude that issue (1) or (2) must be true... How could I set my laptop to allow access to these slave's pages ?

Answer (score 0):

As usual, the answer is in the doc, or the given error ;)

The trick is to follow the error message, as following :

1) open the ports used by the slaves on the internet box (in my case : 5053)

2) add a line on your host file, with the name of the network pointing to the ip of the box (in my case  : @boxIP HP-xw8600-Workstation)

That's should do it ;)

Comment: You could specify your hostname through `--hostname` when launch mesos master or slave.